# Kartik Select2 return null

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, jquery-select2

i have a problem with Kartik Select2. When I want save multiple data in my controller, nothing is saved. And I remove foreach in controller, Yii return me error with information about $university_id IS NULL.

User Form

```
<?= $form->field($user_university, 'university_id')->widget(Select2::classname(),[
    'name' => 'university_id[]',
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(
        \app\models\University::find()->asArray()->all(),
        'id',
        function ($university) {
            return $university['name'];
        }
    ),
    'size' => Select2::MEDIUM,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...', 'multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>
```

User Controller

```
 $user = new User();
    $user->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CREATE;
    $auth_assignment = new AuthAssignment();
    $user_company = new UserCompany();
    $user_university = new UserUniversity();
    $user_status = UserStatus::find()
        ->select('id')
        ->where(['name' => UserStatus::NON_AUTHORIZED_USER])
        ->one();

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $auth_assignment->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $user->auth_key = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
        $user->password_hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($user->password);
        $user->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
        $user->status_id = $user_status->id;
        $user->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        if ($user->save()) {
            $auth_assignment->user_id = $user->id;
            $auth_assignment->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $universities = $user_university->university_id;
            foreach((array) $universities as $university)
            {
                $newUserUniversity = new UserUniversity();
                $newUserUniversity->user_id = $user->id;
                $newUserUniversity->university_id = $university;
                $newUserUniversity->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $newUserUniversity->save(false);

            }...
```

User University Model Rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'university_id', 'created_at'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'university_id','confirm'], 'integer'],
        [['created_at','university_id'], 'safe'],
        [['university_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => University::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['university_id' => 'id']],
        [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `Yii::$app->request->post()` after submit?

Comment: Yii::$app->request->post() return true if form has been sent and sent data as post. User and Auth_assignment is normaly saved, only i can’t save information about user university.

Comment: do you have multiple dropdowns with the name `university_id` in your form ?

Comment: Yes, I use Kartik Select2 to multiple dropdowns. All is good, but returned value is null.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but i know it is a `multi-dropdown` but do you have more than one `multi-dropdowns` for the same field `university_id`?

Comment: and i dont see the `$user_university->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` before you are calling the `$universities = $user_university->university_id;` dont you think that the very next line of `foreach((array) $universities as $university)` will never run once and wont enter  any university data

Comment: Yes, you were right! The problem was in lack $user_university->load(Yii::$app->request->post()). Thanks You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code i can't see where you are loading the data from the post request into the `$user_university` before you start looping on the `university_id`. You need to call `$user_university->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`, look the following piece of code from your script

```
if ($user->save()) {
   $auth_assignment->user_id = $user->id;
   $auth_assignment->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   // this below line will give you an empty string rather than 
   // the selected ids of the `university` that you selected 
   // in the multi-dropdown

   $universities = $user_university->university_id;
```

and the very next line is the `foreach((array) $universities as $university)` in which you are trying to save which won't run even once, as there isnt any array loaded in the `$unversities`. So you can add a call before you get the array from the attribute, dont know if your requirements are to return the user with an error if the data is not loaded for the `$user_university` otherwise you need to add it to the main check

```
if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $auth_assignment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
$user->university->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
```

So your code should look like below

```
$user = new User();
$user->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CREATE;
$auth_assignment = new AuthAssignment();
$user_company = new UserCompany();
$user_university = new UserUniversity();
$user_status = UserStatus::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['name' => UserStatus::NON_AUTHORIZED_USER])
    ->one();

//validate all models
$allModelsValid=$user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $auth_assignment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user_university->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

if ($allModelsValid) {

    $user->auth_key = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
    $user->password_hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($user->password);
    $user->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
    $user->status_id = $user_status->id;
    $user->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $user->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if ($user->save()) {
        $auth_assignment->user_id = $user->id;
        $auth_assignment->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $universities = $user_university->university_id;
        foreach((array) $universities as $university)
        {
            $newUserUniversity = new UserUniversity();
            $newUserUniversity->user_id = $user->id;
            $newUserUniversity->university_id = $university;
            $newUserUniversity->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $newUserUniversity->save(false);

        }...
```

Also apart from above i dont find a reason to use the name as `university_id[]` for the dropdown rather than `university_id`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of Usage of `select2` now currently you are using `Usage with ActiveForm and model` see below multiple ways.

```
use kartik\select2\Select2

// Usage with ActiveForm and model
echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);

// With a model and without ActiveForm
echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'state_2',
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);

// Without model and implementing a multiple select
echo '<label class="control-label">Provinces</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'state_10',
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select provinces ...',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
]);

// A disabled select2 list input
echo '<label class="control-label">State</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'state_11',
    'data' => $data,
    'disabled' => true
]);
```

I guess your problem is in  :

```
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(
        \app\models\University::find()->asArray()->all(),
        'id',
        function ($university) {
            return $university['name'];
        }
    ),
```

Please check data attribute .. check you are passing correct array or not.

Comment: this in now way answers the question, as the question is not about the usage of the plugin, you never addressed the problem in the code that you are bringing the focus on , as the user is able to select the universities from the dropdown and not able to save only, you should not post answers on assumptions